# How to make class Singleton using javax.inject.singleton in android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make the class as singleton in android using @Singleton of **javax.inject.Singleton;**
However, whenever I call new it is creating a new object

Sample Code:

```
import javax.inject.Singleton;

@Singleton
public class KeepOneInstance{
    //Some code

    public void someMethod(){
        //something to do
    }

}
```

from activity calling

```
KeepOneInstance oneInstance = new KeepOneInstance();
oneInstance.someMethod();
```

Comment: ehm ... yes? you mean to say you expect a singleton not to be able to have/create an instance, or do you mean it creates more than one?

Comment: @Stultuske Yes, It creates more than one

Comment: you're not using it correctly. take a look at this text: https://www.baeldung.com/jee-cdi-vs-ejb-singleton

Comment: you mean I need to use @Inject?

Comment: Do you use something like dagger-2 to generate code for for your singleton ?

Comment: @ArtemViter we are not using dagger-2

Comment: Annotation does not do anything itself . Looks like you should use some library for dependencies managements like dagger-2

Comment: Okay.Thanks Will look into that